# Automatically reorder in-text citations based on numbering in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, citing

I'm using BibTeX to manage my bibliography, and have about 250 references. I cannot keep track of the order they were cited in, which leads to some funny formatting. To explain, consider this scenario...

The first citation goes like this `\cite[ref1, ref2, ref3]`, and results in an in-text citation of "[1,2,3]", and also in a bibliography entry of:

1. Ref 1 details
2. Ref 2 details
3. Ref 3 details

All normal so far. The difficulty occurs when I cite these again, but 'out of order', i.e., `\cite[ref3, ref2]`. This results in an in-text citation of "[3,2]". That looks very odd. What I'd like to do is tell LaTeX/BibTeX that order doesn't matter, and for it to automatically make the second citation appear in-text as "[2,3]".

It seems like a petty request in this fake example, but for a full 'book' with over 250 references that are named by authors rather than numbers, there's no way I can do this ordering manually, particularly as references get added or deleted with revisions.

I've tried adding in the command `\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}`, but it came up with this error:

> ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations. (natbib) l.287 ...and`\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`
>   ?

EDIT: Never mind, problem solved, it was as simple as adding `\usepackage{cite}`. Admins, feel free to delete this question.

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, problem solved, it was as simple as adding \usepackage{cite}. Admins, feel free to delete this question.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question; I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: I second @RebeccaJ.Stones.

Comment: I also had this problem.

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem since I was using BibLaTex. I'll leave this here for others in my situation: [Biblatex, numeric style, multicite: Order of references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130940/183394)

Answer (score 6):

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

This package works with the standard `\cite` command and does sorting and compressing.

In order to use **natbib**, one has also to choose a compatible bibliography style, such as `plainnat`.