# Biblatex, numeric style, multicite: Order of references

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `\parencites` for citing and `style=numeric` as `biblatex` option. In the output the references are ordered as in the sourcecode, e.g. `[13, 5, 10]`

Is there a way to get the references in ascending order?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,
    sortcites,
    sorting=nty,
    backref,
    natbib,
    hyperref
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  I'll cite Augustine~\cite{augustine} here,
  and a few others
  here~\parencites{aristotle:poetics}{angenendt}{aksin}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It will output `I'll cite Augustine [4] here, and a few others here [3, 2, 1].`

What I want is: `I'll cite Augustine [4] here, and a few others here [1, 2, 3].`

So just the sorted inside `[ ]` while the bibliography stays sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51434/biblatex-citation-order?rq=1

Comment: @Papiro thanks for your comment, but that's not what I'm looking for. The order in the references section is OK, it's ordered in alphabetical order. What i want is that the references in the text, where I have multiple citations at on place, are ordered numerically. I'd appreciate if you could help me to rephrase the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to specify the option `sortcites=true` in the preamble.
The citations are then sorted according to the global sorting scheme (see more here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51439/35864).

Cite sorting only works with the "normal" `\*cite` commands, not with the `\*cites` ones. This is because in `\cites{a}{b}` each key is processed as if passed to a single `\cite` command. `\cite{a,b}` has the full list available and is thus able to sort the citations.
So if you want sorting, you'll need to use `\parencite{aristotle:poetics,aksin,angenendt}` instead of `\parencites{aristotle:poetics}{angenendt}{aksin}`.

Note that constructions with pre- and postnotes for each entry such as `\parencites[see][2]{aristotle:poetics}[4]{angenendt}[cf.][5]{aksin}` cannot be realised with `\parencite`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it also sorts the bibliography. See my edit and MWE for clarification.

Comment: What sorts the bibliography? The bibliography is sorted by the scheme you have specified (or by the scheme specified by the style you use, if you do not choose to overwrite it), `sortcites` sorts the citations accordingly. The problem you are facing seems to be connected to using `\parencites{aristotle:poetics}{angenendt}{aksin}`, if I use `\parencite{aristotle:poetics,angenendt,aksin}` the sorting works for me. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Hmm... That would be fully OK for me, I was just wondering whether this is sound? The BibLaTeX doc has it only with `{key1}{key2}{key3}`. But maybe that's due to the fact that they use post- and prenotes as well...

Comment: And it works in my real world doc as well :) If you add this to your answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently there is a way to make multicite commands sortable: [Sorting citations using \cites command in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65809/35864).

Comment: With the compressed numeric style in biblatex, `style=ext-numeric-comp` or `style=numeric-comp`, `\cite{a,b,c}` and `\parencite{b,a,c}` and so on produce "[1-3]", whichever order the references are given in.

Comment: @Cicada Indeed. That is because `numeric-comp` (and other `-comp` styles as well) enables `sortcites` in order to have a chance to fully compress the citations.